# List of Dictionary to List<Type> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code snippet into c#

```
public class Client
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}




var liste = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionary["Id"] = "111";
            dictionary["Name"] = "XYZ";
            dictionary["Address"] = "Addd";
            liste.Add(dictionary);
            var result = liste.SelectMany(x => x);

            //Code for Converting result into List<Client>
```

Now I want to create List from the result query using linq

Comment: Well, I _was_ going to post but somehow I feel Jon Skeet will have a better solution. ;p

Comment: Sure it can be done, but it would help if you could tell us why the data has ended up like this. For example, why have you flattened the list of dictionaries? That only makes it harder.

Comment: @Ani:By mistake I pasted that code.My requirement was to covert list<dic> to List of type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you could do something like:

```
var result = liste.Select(map => new Client { ID = map["ID"],
                                              Name = map["Name"],
                                              Address = map["Address"] })
                  .ToList();
```

Is that what you were thinking of? You could make it more general-purpose by iterating over the dictionary and setting properties with reflection... but it would become significantly longer code, of course.

Comment: Damn you beat me to it by the time it takes to click submit!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var q = (from dic in liste
select new Client
{
Id = dic["Id"],
Name = dic["Name"],
Address = dic["Address"],

}).ToList();
```